# converting multiline Table valued function to inline in SQL

Tags: sql, ssms

Considering the performance issues, I wanted to make my `multiline` Table valued function,  an `inline` TVF.

Here is the sample code for `Multiline TVF`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MatchAptNumber (@AptNumberFromUser nvarchar(20))
    RETURNS @MatchedData Table
    (
     RowNumber int  null ,
     PercentMatch int null
    )
AS
Begin

Insert into @MatchedData(RowNumber) select dbo.Patients.Rowid from dbo.Patients where dbo.Patients.Aptnumber = @AptNumberFromUser
update @MatchedData set  PercentMatch= 100

    RETURN;
END;
Go
```

Here is how I use it:

```
select @constVal = FunctionWeight from dbo.FunctionWeights where FunctionWeights.FunctionName = 'MatchAptNumber';

INSERT INTO #Temp2(RowNumber, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
SELECT RowNumber, PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal
from dbo.MatchAptNumber(@Aptnumber);
```

Is it possible to convert it into an inline TVF and use it as mentioned above? I do know the syntactic differences between two but not sure how it be possible to use it the same way? Can I get some pointers on same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the '100' as a constant in the SELECT so the function becomes;

```
CREATE FUNCTION MatchAptNumber (@AptNumberFromUser nvarchar(20))
    RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    SELECT 
        p.Rowid AS RowNumber , 
        CAST(100 AS INT) AS PercentMatch 
    FROM 
        dbo.Patients p
    WHERE 
        p.Aptnumber = @AptNumberFromUser
GO
```